# Data binding: visible depend on list's size (via XML)?

Tags: android-databinding

Android Studio 3.1, java 1.8, Gradle 4.5.

Here my activity:

```
public class OrdersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ObservableArrayList<OrderEntry> orderList = new ObservableArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void setOrderList(List<OrderEntry> list) {
        this.orderList.clear();
        this.orderList.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

I want to show list's size in layout. So here layout's xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.myproject.ui.OrdersActivity" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="@{handler.orderList.size > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>   


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But I get error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  >   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.myproject.ui.OrdersActivity.orderList
  >   file:\app\src\main\res\layout\orders.xml
  >   loc:118:38 - 118:54
  >   ****\ data binding error ****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try making it public or wrapping it with a public `getOrderList()`?

Comment: Yes, I must add public. So with this public ObservableArrayList<OrderEntry> orderList = new ObservableArrayList<>(); work fine. Thanks